# What is the correct way to "pipe" Maven's output in Python to the screen when used in a Python shell script?

Tags: python, unix, shell, maven-2

My Python utility script contains UNIX system calls such as

```
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("ls -ltr")
print "Output: ", output
print "Status: ", status
```

Which work fine and print the output to the console but as soon as I run Maven from the same script,

```
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("mvn clean install -s./../../foo/bar/settings.xml -Dportal -Dmain.dir=${PWD}/../.. -o")
print "Output: ", output
print "Status: ", status
```

The output is not read out like the previous regular system commands. The Maven command in quotes works fine if I simply execute it from the command line. What is the correct way to pipe Maven's output to the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `${PWD}` is properly expanded?    If not, try:

```
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("mvn clean install -s./../../foo/bar/settings.xml -Dportal -Dmain.dir=%s/../.. -o" % os.getcwd ())
```